# Remove inline styles from the_content?

Tags: visual-editor, wysiwyg, css, filters

Is there a way to remove any inline styles made by the WP Editor i.e. Font Size?

Answer (score 1):

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=1522 might be what you are looking for. It's also possible in tinymce to have different levels of editor (minimal, regular, +kitchen sink). Perhaps using one of those may serve your purpose better.